# Question on Borel Cantelli Lemma

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $(\Omega,\mathbb{F},P)$ be a probability space and $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of  iid random variables such that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $r \in [1,\infty)$, $P(X_n > r) = r^{-3/2}$. Are there almost surely infinitely many $n$ such that $X_n \in [n^{1/2},n^{4/3}]$?

This is probably an application of Borel Cantelli lemma. At the moment I have that $P(X_n \geq n^{1/2}) = n^{-3/4}$ and $P(X_n \leq n^{4/3}) = 1 -P(X_n \geq n^{4/3}) = 1 - n^{-2}$. I think I must then find a way to write $P(n^{1/2} \leq X_n \leq n^{4/3})$ using these probabilities. Then I can show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}<P(n^{1/2} \leq X_n \leq n^{4/3}) < \infty$ or that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}<P(n^{1/2} \leq X_n \leq n^{4/3}) = \infty$ and then apply one of the Borel Cantelli lemmas.

Comment: @FShrike I assume so - this is a past paper question that doesn't have a mark-scheme, and I've written it out exactly how its written in the paper

Comment: I'm too tired, I will think about it tomorrow

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: On reflection, the question must mean this instead: (is it true that) “for almost all $\omega\in\Omega$, there are infinitely many $n$ such that $X_n(\omega)\in[n^{1/2},n^{4/3}]$.” My previous statement is definitely wrong since we can explicitly calculate: $$\operatorname{Pr}(X_n\in[n^{1/2},n^{4/3}])=n^{-3/4}-n^{-2}<1$$

Comment: Doesn't that completely resolve the question? Since
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty P\left(X_n\in\left[n^\frac{1}{2},n^\frac{4}{3}\right]\right)=\infty
$$
then the answer to the question must be "yes" by the second Borell-Cantelli lemma.

Comment: I agree with Lonza, I forgot about the second lemma. This completes the proof.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera thank you - thats what I ended up with but it just seemed a little too simple